# Glue ETL Script to load Daily Files not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I'm trying to create a glue script with a dynamicFrame lambda filter to filter my records that were modified in the last 24 hours in my source RDS. The output of this is intended to be written to S3 bucket.

1. Running the job just creates a set of empty file (0 Bytes) on the S3. Is my implementation correct, any bugs?
2. How to parametrize the S3 location with the dynamic current date (directory) for that table ?

CODE SNIPPET:

```
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)
current_date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "db1", table_name = "table1", transformation_ctx = "datasource0")
```

### Filter Dataset to list only rows updated last 24 hours using Dynamic Frame Navtive Filtering

```
dailydataset_dyF = Filter.apply(frame = datasource0, f = lambda x: x["updated_date"] > datetime.datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1))
applymapping1 = ApplyMapping.apply(frame = dailyorder_dyF, mappings = [("")

datasink2 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame = applymapping1, connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"path": "s3://location/table1/current_date"}, format = "csv", transformation_ctx = "datasink2")

job.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Add column for current date and then partition on it during write operation.it will create new partition for each date